# Dmcloud Api : How to Get thumbnails of the Video Uploaded on Dmcloud with java Api?

Tags: thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I am Using Dmcloud java Api for uploading video on dmcloud.but theres's api doesnt give much information about how to get the thumbnail of the particular video.

i can get the stream url download url and evrything.so if any one can give me proper guidance for this..

Answer (score 3):

To get thumbnail url of a particular video, use the get_assets method in cloudkey object.

Ex :

```
String thumbnail_url = cloud.mediaGetAssets(media_id, assets_name);
```

Where assets_name is an array of needed asset like :

```
'jpeg_thumbnail_small',
'jpeg_thumbnail_medium',
'jpeg_thumbnail_large',
'jpeg_thumbnail_source'
```

If it doesn't work, thinks that i'm using PHP API, and my working method is :

```
return $this->cloudkey->media->get_assets(array('id'=>$idMedia,'assets_names'=>array('jpeg_thumbnail_large')));
```

Comment: do I need to set the thumbnail of the video upon upload so that I can get its corresponding thumbnail? Is it still possible to get thumbnails of videos that were already uploaded?

Comment: There is an option in the [Backoffice](https://www.dmcloud.net/backoffice/) that enabled the [thumbnail process](https://www.dmcloud.net/backoffice/settings/encoding/) (activate by default I guess). So all of youre films would have a thumbnail attached... If it not the case, you can activate it, and relaunch the thumbnail process (using the backoffice if you have just few videos, and using the API otherwise)